# create simple atl object with connection points Fire methods not being generated

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, com, atl

I created ATL dll project in visual studio 2008 and it generated the following class...

template <class T>
class CProxy_IAutomateEvents : public IConnectionPointImpl<T, &__uuidof( _IAutomateEvents ), CComDynamicUnkArray>
{
    //Warning this class will  be regenerated by the wizard.
public:
};

I have added methods to the IAutomateEvents dispinterface in the idl and recompiled. I can't figure out how to get it to generate the Fire_ methods. Which wizard is it talking about? I don't want to do it manually because I might do it in a fashion that might be out of date or get replaced if run said wizard at some point. 
I find all this stuff about right clicking on the class and choosing add connection point but that option doesn't show up. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind. My class view included a CLASS as well as the interface called IAutomate. That is what I was right clicking that did not support Add Connection Point. I finally noticed the CAutomate class and right clicked it, chose add connection point and then just hit finish and all my Fire_ functions are now implemented. 
Sorry if I wasted anybodies time.

Answer (score 2):

When you update event interface, proxy class is not updated automatically, so when you are done with changes, you need to re-generate proxy class so that new methods appear on it.

To re-generate the proxy class, you open Class View for your project, then you locate your class and through context menu you choose Add, Add Connection Point. Don't worry about connection point already implemented, just add it as if it is the first time. Your class will be updated, and so will be the proxy class with event generation methods.